# Reload jquery treeview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jstree

i have treeview in my page

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.treeview.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 $("#ulmenu").treeview({ Expanded: true });
```

and some buttons like add, edit, delete ,refresh.
My questian is how can i reload the treeview when clicking the refresh button without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1572213.aspx/1 might help,

Comment: What do yo mean by refresh? How do you load jsTree? Do yo use ajax load?